# How to Draw a COLZ TH2F from a TTree?

Tags: histogram, root-framework, histogram2d

I am trying to draw a COLZ plot i.e. a 2D histogram with a colour bar, from a Tree, and be able to define the number of bins myself.
My Tree is called event:

I have tried:

```
event->Draw("x:y>>hist1(1000,100,500,1000,0,500)", "x>100");
TH2F * hist1 = (TH2F*)gDirectory->Get("hist1");
hist1->Draw("COLZ");
```

and:

```
event->Draw("x:y>>hist1(1000,100,500,1000,0,500)", "x>100", "COLZ");
TH2F * hist1 = (TH2F*)gDirectory->Get("hist1");
hist1->Draw();
```

But neither will draw the histogram.

This will draw a scatter plot:

```
event->Draw("x:y>>hist1(1000,100,500,1000,0,500)", "x>100");
TH2F * hist1 = (TH2F*)gDirectory->Get("hist1");
hist1->Draw();
```

This will draw a COLZ plot but using this method I'm unable to define bin sizes myself:

```
 event->Draw("x:y", "x>100", "COLZ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer Keldorn but the problem lay within part of my code that I had not posted.

I was accessing my root file using:

```
 TFile f("file.root"); 
 TTree* event = (TTree*)f.Get("EventTree");
```

Changing this to:

```
TFile *f = new TFile("file.root");
TTree* event = (TTree*)f->Get("EventTree");
```

fixed all of my histogram problems!

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you. There's something fishy though, both should be equally valid. So you probably still have a problem somewhere, which might reveal itself with another symptom at some point.

Comment: That is probably because it is not. Like a memory leak earlier with random-ish side effects. That's why a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Answer (score 3):

I can not reproduce the issue, your first try works for me:

```
event->Draw("x:y>>hist1(1000,100,500,1000,0,500)", "x>100");
TH2F * hist1 = (TH2F*)gDirectory->Get("hist1");
hist1->Draw("COLZ");
```

It can also work in a single line:

```
event->Draw("x:y>>hist1(1000,100,500,1000,0,500)", "x>100", "COLZ");
```

In your 3rd case, if `hist1->Draw();` draws a scatter plot, then `hist1->Draw("COLZ");` should work too. Did you run exactly the same way? If so, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Note: the result of `hist1->Draw();` is *not* a scatter plot (ROOT is misleading here), it is a histogram where bin contents are represented by dots. See e.g. [this plot](https://root-forum.cern.ch/uploads/default/original/2X/5/5e1d493c3d8e4d8509a12477f90d1c4c72d1b37c.jpg) where you can guess the underlying bins.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the results as in my original post. I can't see how we are doing anything differently but mine simply doesn't work. I agree in the 3rd case it should work as I get a plot without "COLZ" in my call to ->Draw(), but it doesn't plot anything.